# SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /

Tags: javascript, regex

According to http://www.regexr.com/38o5d my reqex seems to work, but when I implement it into my javascript

`var prefix = hash.replace(/\/|#/g, '');`

I'll get the following error: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: missing /

Comment: I don't get that error when I run that code.

Comment: Also you should use a character class (`[#/]`) for one character alternation.

Comment: @Robin You don't need to escape the `/` within a character class.

Comment: @devnull: I usually change delimiters to avoid the question, so never knew... You're right, thanks!

Comment: I found the error, when I called the method I did it method(/) instead of method('/'). And Robin, thanks, didn't know that I could shorten it to /[#/]/g

Comment: I got this error when I had a comment in my js that had only one `"/ comment"`. Should be `"// comment"`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Psychic debugging: Your code isn't in a plain JavaScript or HTML file, but is being printed from a scripting language in which `#` is a comment character.  The `#/g, '');` piece is being treated as a comment in your script.

You need to add some quotes to ensure that the whole line gets printed.